# MySQL - Filter result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to filter result of my SQL query. I want to select everything that has some specific text in some column.

Example:

> SELECT * FROM categories WHERE *(name
>   has 'abc' values in it's value ex.
>   MyabcCategory)*

Also maybe it is not very good idea to do that in query, maybe it is better to get all and then filter array instead? But I don't know how to do that aether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LIKE` with `%` wildcard:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE name LIKE '%abc%'
```

This will give you all the records that have `abc` somewhere in them.

[You can learn more about it here :)](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [`LIKE` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), with `%` to match any character before and after your specific word :

```
select *
from categories
where name like '%abc%';
```

But note that doing so, MySQL will scan each line of the table, every time the query is executed... which might not be great if you have a lot of data.

If you're searching for some kind of text, you might either want to :

- Use a [`FULLTEXT` index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), if you're working with MyISAM tables.
- Or, use a solution that's separated from MySQL, with a specific indexing/search engine, such as [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Comment: Thanks :-) I haven't been on SO a lot, these last few months ; too many things to do... Not sure I'll stay, but, today, I had a bit of time, and missed the old days ^^

Comment: We are missing a fount of knowledge especially in PHP tag. I hope you manage time for it some day :) Thanks

Comment: Maybe, who knows :-) ;; anyway, nice to you're still here !

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE name LIKE '%abc%'
```